# Playback controls in Graph Editor

Tags: shortcut, graph-editor

Newer versions of Blender no longer have the playback control bar in Graph Editor.

I can sort of control the playback with the space bar play/pause, but there seems to be no shortcut to move the playhead back to Frame 1? I'm having to click it with the mouse every time. Is there a shortcut for this or is there a place in the keymap to set it?

Comment: Shift + Left Arrow are the keys to move to frame 1

Comment: I don't think thee graph ever had playback controls? At least [the manual seems to agree with me](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/graph_editor/introduction.html). People usually keep a timeline editor reduced down to its header height to keep all the nice animation tools.

Comment: I agree with @L0Lock - I don't know when you used the _Graph Editor_ the last time, but I have an old version 2.79 here and there it is just like in the most recent version: only the _Timeline_ has playback controls, neither the _Graph Editor_ nor the _Video Sequence Editor_ or the _Movie Editor_ have them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operation to jump to beginning or end of frame range is apparently "jump to endpoint."  While this operation doesn't seem to have any relevant operator panel parameters, it's used for both operations.  It works at least in graph editor and timeline.  Used from searchbar, it jumps to first frame in range.

For me, these are bound to shift + right arrow (end of frame range) and shift + left arrow (beginning of frame range), but I use the 2.79 keybinding set, and I don't know if they exist in other keybinding sets.  The keybinding appears to have an operator-panel-like parameter Boolean "last frame" which is set differently for each bind.

[image]